# Как с помощью Python открыть программу или файл

Tags: python, python-3.x

С помощью чего можно открыть любой файл? Не для чтения, не для записи, просто открыть так, как бы если бы я нажал два раза по иконке программы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать модуль `os`:

```
import os

file_path = r'C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe'
os.system("start "+file_path)
```

Comment: А зачем вы написали r вот второй строчке? И как можно запустить от администратора?

Comment: @Tryr r чтобы не обрабатывался \ как символ экранирования

Comment: С r у меня не работало, когда убрал все работает